# Objective c- post image received corrupted

Tags: ios, objective-c, http-post

I am trying to post an image to a web server, for some reason the file is received corrupted and with a size of (102)

I have done searches on the forum but could not find any solution to my problem.
any help will be blessed!

my code below:

```
    - (void)postItemImage:(UIImage*)image withKey:(NSString*)key andItemid:(int)itemId;

{
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);
    NSLog(@"inside postItemImage");
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kBasePostUrl]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"
    ;
    NSData *boundryData = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    [body appendData:boundryData];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Request\"\r\n\r\n%@", @"addItemMedia"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:boundryData];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"picture\"; filename=\"swapper.jpg\"; \r\n"]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:boundryData];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:boundryData];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];

    [body appendData:boundryData];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userId\"\r\n\r\n%d", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:kUserIDKey]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:boundryData];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"itemId\"\r\n\r\n%d", itemId] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:boundryData];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"itemMediaType\"\r\n\r\n%@", key] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:boundryData];


    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        NSLog(@"Do in background");
        //Do in background
        NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
               if (returnData) {
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                //Do in Main thread
                NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSLog(@"return: %@", returnString);
                [self.delegate uploadFinishedWithResponse:returnString];
           });
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: NSURLConnection is asynchronous. Why do you want it to dispatch with synchronous request? Just curious to know.

Comment: I I have previously succeessfuly tested the api using this code, so I tried to restore a working code as is....

Answer (score 0):

When you are transferring images, I would suggest using base64.

you should encode it from sender then decode is on the other.

There are lots of tutorial online on how to encode/decode base64.